# PHP foreach overwrite value with array

Tags: php, arrays, templates

I'm making a simple PHP Template system but I'm getting an error I cannot solve, the thing is the layout loads excellent but many times, can't figure how to solve, here my code

```
Class Template {

private $var = array();

public function assign($key, $value) {

    $this->vars[$key] = $value;

}

public function render($template_name) {

    $path = $template_name.'.tpl';
    if (file_exists($path)) {

        $content = file_get_contents($path);

        foreach($this->vars as $display) {


            $newcontent = str_replace(array_keys($this->vars, $display), $display, $content);
            echo $newcontent;

        }

    } else {

        exit('<h1>Load error</h1>');

    }
}
```

}

And the output is

Title is : Welcome to my template system

Credits to [credits]

Title is : [title]

Credits to Credits to Alvaritos

As you can see this is wrong, but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: isn't it better to use **SMARTY**?

Comment: I want to create my own class just for practise.

Comment: @Robert: if you just need variable replacements, without if/else/for logic - no, not really

Comment: For practise it's good but if you want create something that was already written and it's good there's no sense. @OneTrickPony soon in project such needs may be required in view layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off with [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$new = strtr($content, $this->vars);
print $new;
```

`str_replace()` does the replaces in the order the keys are defined. If you have variables like `array('a' => 1, 'aa' => 2)` and a string like `aa`, you will get `11` instead of `2`. `strtr()` will order the keys by length before replacing (highest first), so that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
foreach($this->vars as $key => $value)
    $content = str_replace($key,$value,$content);
echo $content;
```